# Passing string from model that is created on certain condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I just happaned to have some troubles. 
I have a model with a function

```
public class Profile
{
   public void PrintResult()
   {
       if(1 == 1)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("equals 1");
            if(2 == 2)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("equals 2");
            }
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine("error");
       }
   }
}
```

this is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Profile p = new Profile();
    p.PrintResult();

    return View();
}
```

Well, I know that `console.writeline` or `response.write`.
So, my question is:  how could I make those console.writeline to things like

```
string s = "Equals 2";
```

instead of `console.writelines` which does not working obviously and then call it somehow both `equals 1` and `equals 2` show in the view.

Been googling for quite long and couldn't find an answer.
If you need more info to help me, tell me @_ @

Comment: basicly you should not have methods like this in your model

Comment: What do you want to achieve? seems uncleared to me!

Comment: @Div To allow somehow at choosing where would I want my strings from if() and put those somewhere in the view with viewbag or somehing like that. Should I have this function in controller instead?

Comment: Question is not very clear.. Also Recheck the conditions once in your PrintResult Method.. you used assignment operator to check if values are equal..

Comment: yes , if you wants to use ViewBag it should be in controller

Comment: Sandip is right, you can use `ViewBag` only in controller

Comment: still not clear what you wants to store in ViewBag? only "equals 1" OR something else

Comment: @SandipPatel, *still not clear what you wants* So please make sure you get it first and then give answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of console.writeline, you have to return **comma seperated string** Or **list** of string

```
public List<string> PrintResult()
{
    var listItems = new List<string>();
    if (1 == 1)
    {
        listItems.Add("equal 1");
        if (2 == 2)
        {
            listItems.Add("equal 2");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        listItems.Add("error");
    }

    return listItems;
}
```

Comment: Well, this seems like a best option to do that. Tho, I should avoid doing that @_ @ as everybody says... probably.

Answer (score 1):

Return a comma separated list from your model in this case(Though i do not support coding such kind of models.Think this is for your practise).

```
public class Profile
{
    public string PrintResult()
   {
       string strSample="";
                if(1 == 1)
                {
                     if(strSample=="")
                     {
                     strSample="equals 1";
                     }
                    else
                     {
                       strSample+=","+"equals1";
                     }



                    if(2 == 2){
                       if(strSample=="")
                     {
                     strSample="equals 2";
                     }
                    else
                     {
                       strSample+=","+"equals2";
                     }

                    |
                }else
                {
                    if(strSample=="")
                     {
                     strSample="error";
                     }
                    else
                     {
                       strSample+=","+"error";
                     }

                }
   }
}
```

Now In your controller pass this string returned from the model to your view as follows

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Profile p = new Profile();
    string sample=p.PrintResult();

    return View((object)sample);
}
```

Now in your `Index` View, make the view as strongly typed to a string like below

```
@model string 
<h1>@Model</h1>
```